# gradient descent momentum vs step size

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, optimization, gradient-descent, calculus

In the gradient descent method, the learning rate (which is multiplied by the results of the gradient on each weight) identifies the size of the step (steep down) that the algorithm takes in each iteration to reduce the objective cost function. How does it differ from the parameter `momentum`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum is a whole different method, that uses parameter that works as an average of previous gradients.

Precisely in **Gradient Descent** (let's denote learning rate by $\eta$)

$$w_{i+1} = w_i - \eta \nabla F(w)$$

Whereas in **Momentum Method**

$$w_{i+1} = w_i - \gamma v_i$$

Where

$$v_{i+1} = \beta v_i + (1 - \beta)  \nabla F(w)$$

Note that this method has *two* hyperparameters, instead of one like in GD, so I can't be sure if your `momentum` means $\gamma$ or $\beta$. If you use some software though, it should have two parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. I am using (stochastic gradient descent SGD) implementation by scikit-learn here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html. I thought `Momentum` is another parameter of SDG (as stated in the link) but you are saying it is not

Comment: Shouldn't you swap out $\gamma$ with $\eta$?  They are the same thing and you are confusing OP.

Comment: @generic_user I wanted to emphasise that these are two different methods. I also think this way is actually less confusing.

Comment: They're really not.  Momentum is just gradient descent with an extra feature.

Comment: @generic_user well that's an opinion. They are different in that they update the weights with different values. Also, don't you think that this discussion is more confusing than the parameter naming issue? ;)

Comment: At minimum we can agree that they are closely related.  Standard SGD has a single, global step size.  Momentum has a global step size and a weight-specific step size also.

Comment: I would agree that they aren't different methods. GD with momentum is just a specific way of choosing the step-size; its a linear combination of the previous direction and the current gradient. $\beta$ is the momentum as this is the amount of weight you put on the previous direction.

Comment: @JakubBartczuk They both employ the same method, just the scaling of the past gradients is different. You can see that when you write down the closed form.

And the $v_i$ in the first equation of momentum is supposed to be a $v_{i+1}$ and the $\nabla F(w)$'s should each be $\nabla F(w_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Classical gradient descent has the shape:

$$\mathbf{x}_{i+1} = \mathbf{x}_i - \gamma \cdot\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_i)$$

for a differentiable function $f$, some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ (the "learning rate" you referred to) and a starting point $\mathbf{x}_{0}$.

With "momentum" is meant the following adaption,

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{i+1} &= \mathbf{x}_i - \alpha \cdot \mathbf{z}_{i+1} \\
\text{whereat}\quad \mathbf{z}_{i+1} &= \beta \cdot \mathbf{z}_{i} + \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_i)
\end{align}$$

where $\mathbf{z}$ can be interpreted as a momentum.

If you write down the closed form, you get

$$\mathbf{x}_{i+1} = \mathbf{x}_{0} - \gamma \cdot \sum^i_{k=0} \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

for the "classical" version and

$$\mathbf{x}_{i+1} = \mathbf{x}_{0} - \alpha \cdot \sum^i_{k=0} \dfrac{1-\beta^{i-k+1}}{1-\beta}\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_k)$$

for the "momentum" version.

As you can see, they are both pretty much the same (the class is called *Linear First Order Methods*). Momentum just puts greater emphasis on the recent gradients, whereas the classic version treats them equally (as illustrated below).

[image: coefficient]